# Finding difference of values between corresponding fields in two CSV files

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have been trying to find difference of values between corresponding fields in two CSV files

```
$ cat f1.csv
A,B,25,35,50
C,D,30,40,36
$
$ cat f2.csv
E,F,20,40,50
G,H,22,40,40
$
```

Desired output:

```
5 -5 0   
8 0 -4
```

I could able to achieve it like this:

```
$ paste -d "," f1.csv f2.csv
A,B,25,35,50,E,F,20,40,50
C,D,30,40,36,G,H,22,40,40
$
$ paste -d "," f1.csv f2.csv | awk -F, '{print $3-$8 " " $4-$9 " " $5-$10 }'
5 -5 0
8 0 -4
$
```

Is there any better way to achieve it with `awk` alone without `paste` command?

Comment: Yes, but it makes it more incomprehensible.

Comment: can there be more than 2 lines in each file? what happens if the number of lines don't match (eg, `f1.csv` has 3 lines and `f2.csv` has 1 or 8 lines)?; will there always be 5 comma-delimited fields? will we always be looking at comparing fields #3, #4, #5 or do we need to dynamically determine which fields are numeric? do we have to worry about a numeric value in a field with a non-numeric in the 'matching' field from the other file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first step replace only `paste` with `awk`:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR {file1[FNR]=$0; next} {print file1[FNR] FS $0}' f1.csv f2.csv
```

Output:

```
A,B,25,35,50,E,F,20,40,50
C,D,30,40,36,G,H,22,40,40
```

---

Then split `file1[FNR] FS $0` to an array with `,` as field separator:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR {file1[FNR]=$0; next} {split(file1[FNR] FS $0, arr, FS); print arr[3]-arr[8], arr[4]-arr[9], arr[5]-arr[10]}' f1.csv f2.csv
```

Output:

```
5 -5 0
8 0 -4
```

---

From `man awk`:

> `FNR`:         The input record number in the current input file.

> `NR`:          The total number of input records seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using nl and awk

```
$ (nl f1.csv;nl f2.csv) | sort | awk -F, ' {a1=$3;a2=$4;a3=$5; getline; print a1-$3,a2-$4,a3-$5 } ' 
5 -5 0
8 0 -4
$
```